# Decorator write by myself with python,why the function name will affect the program running speed

Tags: python

When I do dynamic programming, I use decorators to save intermediate results.When I implement the decorator myself, I find that the name of the function returned must be the same as the name of the function passed in, so that  will faster, but I don't know why.the code like this,if i write r = memo(r) and r(300) run very fast;but if i write fun = memo(r) then fun(300) run slowly.
i want to know how decorators works ,thanks.

```
def memo(func):
    coach={}
    def _w(n):
        if n in coach:
            result = coach[n]
        else:
            result = func(n)
            coach[n]=result
        return result
    return _w
def r(n):
    sub_price,sub_split =  max(
        [(price[n],n)]+[(r(i)+r(n-i),i) for i in range(1,n)],
        key = lambda x:x[0])
    if n not in solution:
        solution[n] = (sub_split,n-sub_split)
    #print(n,"  ",sub_split,"   ",n-sub_split,"   ",sub_price)
    return sub_price

r = memo(r)                            fun = memo(r)  
r(300)                                 fun(300)#very slow
# fast      
#this speed just like 
#@memo
#def r( )
```

Comment: "I find that the name of the function returned must be the same as the name of the function passed in,so that will faster" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean. Do not paste code (especially without code fences) into comments.

Comment: @sepp2k     sorry,i am just use this greate tools

Comment: @gmds  sorry,i am just use this greate tools,and i add the ccode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun = memo(r)
```

This is slow because here `r` still refers to the original non-memoized version of the function, so when `r` calls itself it does not go through the lookup table and so you have the same complexity as without the memoization. Here the memoization only makes a difference when you call `fun` multiple times with the same argument. The recursive calls of `r` are not affected.

When you reassign `r`, that also affects the recursive calls, so you actually change the complexity of the function.

Comment: i have know your means,thanks